# Restangular does not work with relative URL

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using angular.js and I have a module which uses a web service

```
/* Rest WS Config */
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(ENVL.apiEndpoint+'/ig-web/services');
```

It works fine.

I would like to use the relative way of setting my base URL (beacuse I must not provide a specific configuration per environment) so I tried:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/ig-web/services');
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('./ig-web/services');
```

But that did not work.

Any ideas ?

Herehunder the complete module file

```
'use strict';

angular.module('env.config', [])
.constant('ENVL', {
    'name': 'development local',
    'apiEndpoint': 'http://localhost:8080'
})
.constant('DEVT', {
    'name': 'development server',
    'apiEndpoint': 'http://domain.dev'
})
.constant('INT', {
    'name': 'integration server',
    'apiEndpoint': 'http://domain.int'
})
.constant('REC', {
    'name': 'recette server',
    'apiEndpoint': 'http://domain.rec'
});


var app = angular.module('saisinesApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngResource',
'ui.bootstrap',
'toaster',
'angular.css.injector',
'angularFileUpload',
'dialogs',
'ui.router.state',
'ajoslin.promise-tracker',
'cgBusy',
'restangular',
'ngGrid',
'xeditable',
'env.config',
'saisinesAppFilters'])
.constant('_', window._)
.constant('jsPDF',window.jsPDF);

 app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider,ENVL) {
/* Rounting config*/
$urlRouterProvider.when('/home', '/home/search');

$stateProvider
    .state('auth', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'src/auth/authentication.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
    })
    .state('auth-by-url', {
        url: '/:token',
        templateUrl: 'src/auth/authentication.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
    })
    .state('home', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'src/common/header.html',
        controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
    })
    .state('home.search', {
        url: '/search',
        templateUrl: 'src/search/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    })
    .state('home.search-by-siren', {
        url: '/search/:siren',
        templateUrl: 'src/search/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    })
    .state('home.create', {
        url: '/create',
        templateUrl: 'src/create/create.html',
        controller: 'CreateCtrl'
    })
    .state('home.recap', {
        url: '/recap',
        templateUrl: 'src/recap/recap.html'
    });

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

 /* Rest WS Config */
//RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(ENVL.apiEndpoint+'/ig-web/services');
 RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('./ig-web/services');
 });

 app.run([
'$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}
]);
```

Comment: What version of Restangular are you using? RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/ig-web/services'); is a proper call. I've never seen using a './' for the url, but the first option you mentioned should work properly. Are you receiving an error? In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I hope it will help someone if they have the same problem.

When I was testing in local, I was using a grunt server with the port 8000

But my web services were located on the port 8080 (which corresponds to the ENV constant).

Thus there was no way that my web services could work with the port of grunt if I let the relative path.

However, when using JBOSS and the relative path, it works because now the relative path points to the correct adress.

Thus my correct configuration is:

```
'use strict';


 var app = angular.module('saisinesApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngResource',
'ui.bootstrap',
'toaster',
'angular.css.injector',
'angularFileUpload',
'dialogs',
'ui.router.state',
'ajoslin.promise-tracker',
'cgBusy',
'restangular',
'ngGrid',
'xeditable',
'saisinesAppFilters'])
.constant('_', window._)
.constant('jsPDF',window.jsPDF);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider) {
/* Rounting config*/
$urlRouterProvider.when('/home', '/home/search');

$stateProvider
.state('auth', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'src/auth/authentication.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl'
 })
.state('auth-by-url', {
    url: '/:token',
    templateUrl: 'src/auth/authentication.html',
    controller: 'AuthCtrl'
 })
.state('home', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'src/common/header.html',
    controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
})
.state('home.search', {
    url: '/search',
    templateUrl: 'src/search/search.html',
    controller: 'SearchCtrl'
})
.state('home.search-by-siren', {
    url: '/search/:siren',
    templateUrl: 'src/search/search.html',
    controller: 'SearchCtrl'
})
.state('home.create', {
    url: '/create',
    templateUrl: 'src/create/create.html',
    controller: 'CreateCtrl'
})
.state('home.recap', {
    url: '/recap',
    templateUrl: 'src/recap/recap.html'
 });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

/* Rest WS Config */
 RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/ig-web/services');
});

app.run([
'$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
 $rootScope.$state = $state;
 $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}
]);
```